# How can I get symbol link name in windows NT driver?

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I'm writing a windows nt driver. I define a `DEVICE_EXTENSION`

```
typedef struct _DEVICE_EXTENSION {
PDEVICE_OBJECT pDevice;
UNICODE_STRING ustrDeviceName;
UNICODE_STRING ustrSymLinkName;
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, *PDEVICE_EXTENSION;
```

And I create a device,

```
status = IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject,
    sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION),
    &devName,
    FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
    0, TRUE,
    &pDevObj);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{ 
    DbgPrint("CreateDevice Error...\n");
    return status;
}
pDevObj->Flags |= DO_BUFFERED_IO;
pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)pDevObj->DeviceExtension;
pDevExt->pDevice = pDevObj;
pDevExt->ustrDeviceName = devName;

UNICODE_STRING symLinkName;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&symLinkName, DOS_DEVICE_NAME);
pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName = symLinkName;
status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&symLinkName, &devName);
```

you can see, I store `symLinkName` in `DEVICE_EXTENSION` pDevExt. When it unloads from device, I read this `symLinkName`

```
NTSTATUS status;
PDEVICE_OBJECT  pNextObj;
DbgPrint(("Enter DriverUnload\n"));
pNextObj = pDriverObject->DeviceObject;
UNICODE_STRING pLinkName;

while (pNextObj != NULL)
{
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)pNextObj->DeviceExtension;
    RtlCopyUnicodeString(&pLinkName, &(pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName));
    DbgPrint("Start delete symlinkname %wZ ...\n", &pLinkName);n // meet a error
    status = IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&pLinkName);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Delete SymbolLink Error\n");
        goto finish;
    }
    pNextObj = pNextObj->NextDevice;
    IoDeleteDevice(pDevExt->pDevice);
}
```

Before executing `IoDeleteSymbolicLink`, I want to print this `pLinkName`, but I meet a error.

[image]
To solve this problem ,I try many methods.

```
while (pNextObj != NULL)
{
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)pNextObj->DeviceExtension;
    // RtlCopyUnicodeString(&pLinkName, &(pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName));
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&pLinkName, DOS_DEVICE_NAME);     
    DbgPrint("Start delete symlinkname %wZ ...\n", &pLinkName);
    status = IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&pLinkName);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Delete SymbolLink Error\n");
        goto finish;
    }
    pNextObj = pNextObj->NextDevice;
    IoDeleteDevice(pDevExt->pDevice);
}
```

this will execute successfully, but I don't know why this happen.

Comment: because your call to `RtlCopyUnicodeString` wrong and senseless

Comment: "The caller must properly initialize all members of the structure pointed to by DestinationString before calling RtlCopyUnicodeString. Failure to initialize the Length or the MaximumLength member before calling this routine can cause a buffer overrun."

Comment: @RbMm If I do not use `RtlCopyUnicodeString`,  just like this `IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&(pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName))`. I will meet the error again. So I think `pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName` should has been released by now.

Comment: at first use `RtlCopyUnicodeString` absolute senseless. can you explain (for self) - for what you make copy of string ? at second `pLinkName` not initialized before you call `RtlCopyUnicodeString` as result and crash. finally for what need create sym links at all ?

Comment: @RbMm First, I just use this to test something. OK, I do not use `RtlCopyUnicodeString`. Now I want to use `pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName` as parameter to delete symbolic link like this `IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&(pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName))`. So it's nothing about `RtlCopyUnicodeString`, I use this with wrong. I just want to know why this happens.

Comment: *I do not use RtlCopyUnicodeString* - but look for your code - `RtlCopyUnicodeString(&pLinkName, &(pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName));`, but look for your crash dump. i nothing understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using this `#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)` in your code. If so, this is the explanation:

```
/* 
 * These compiler directives tell the Operating System how to load the
 * driver into memory. The "INIT" section is discardable as you only
 * need the driver entry upon initialization, then it can be discarded.
 *
 */
```

After loading, `INIT` sesison will be discarded and your `pDevExt->ustrSymLinkName` data has been released if it is in that session. You can remove all `#pragma alloc_text` to avoid this problem.

Comment: how all this related to src of error ? nothing explain and wrong